jenkins agent cannot use jnlp in kubernates
after my pipeline works, the Console Output struck at

Still waiting to schedule task
‘jenkins-agent-nrcx0’ is offline

and i get logs from my jenkins-agent pod, that is
Oct 16, 2024 9:00:19 AM hudson.remoting.Launcher$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://jenkins-service.jenkins/]
Oct 16, 2024 9:00:49 AM hudson.remoting.Launcher$CuiListener status
INFO: Could not locate server among [http://jenkins-service.jenkins/]; waiting 10 seconds before retry
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to http://jenkins-service.jenkins/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: Connect timed out
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:229)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:881)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:588)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:226)

and the logs from jenkins-master is
Oct 16, 2024 9:00:19 AM hudson.remoting.Launcher$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://jenkins-service.jenkins/]
Oct 16, 2024 9:00:49 AM hudson.remoting.Launcher$CuiListener status
INFO: Could not locate server among [http://jenkins-service.jenkins/]; waiting 10 seconds before retry
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to http://jenkins-service.jenkins/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: Connect timed out
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:229)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:881)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:588)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:226)

this is a old problem that many people had asked. I have read their answers, where the most mentioned part is "chose 'random' option for 'Agents: TCP port for JNLP agents'. I have try, but it doesn't work.
